# Почему не работает программа, когда боту пишут много людей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Есть Telegram-бот, который выдаёт случайное имя из файла, на библиотеке `telebot`. Вот код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random
name=open('C:\\Users\\user\\naames.txt')
names=name.read()
nnn=names[:].split('.')
aaa=[]
nnn2=nnn[:]
names=names.split('.')
nnn3=names[:]
name.close()
bot = telebot.TeleBot('мой токен')
def fu(cu):
    global names
    global aaa
    aaa.append(cu)
    sa=random.choice(nnn3)
    msg = 'Тебе выпал(а): '+sa
    nnn3.remove(sa)
    name=open('C:\\Users\\user\\naames.txt', 'w')
    name.write('.'.join(names))
    name.close()
    return msg

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    global names
    global pert
    if message.text=='/start':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='''
Приветствую тебя, мой дорогой друг✨

Напиши фамилию и имя''')
        file = open('C:\\Users\\user\\photo.png', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file)
    else:
        if message.text in nnn:
            pert=message.text
            if message.from_user.first_name and message.from_user.last_name:
                print('ID: '+str(message.from_user.id)+' ; NAME: '+message.from_user.first_name+' '+message.from_user.last_name)
            elif message.from_user.first_name:
                print('ID: '+str(message.from_user.id)+' ; NAME: '+message.from_user.first_name)
            elif message.from_user.last_name:
                print('ID: '+str(message.from_user.id)+' ; NAME: '+message.from_user.last_name)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, "+message.text.split()[1]+"!")
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            key_n = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Имя!', callback_data='name')
            keyboard.add(key_n)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Жми кнопку!', reply_markup=keyboard)
        else:
            print(message.text+' - такого имени нет - отказ;')
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Такого имени нет!\nПроверь, что ты ввёл всё верно.')
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
  global s
  global aaa
  if pert not in aaa:
      
      while True:
          s=fu(pert)
          if s != pert and pert.split()[0]!=s.split()[0]: break
      bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, s)
      print(pert+' - '+s)
  else:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ты уже смотрел(а) имя!')
        print(pert+' - отказ - имя уже просмотрено')
print('Запуск\n\n\n')
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout = 1111120)
```

В файле `naames.txt` хранятся имена через точку. Пробовал запускать программу с двух компьютеров, всё нормально. Запустили примерно 40-50 человек - всё стало путаться, выдавалось по 5 имён, иногда давал одинаковые.

В чём проблема? Можно ли её исправить?

**P.S. Знаю, что код можно сократить, но писать мне это не надо, т.к. мне так удобнее**

Comment: Не знаю питон. Но похоже, что проблема в том, что файл не предназначен, чтобы в него писать в несколько потоков - будут конфликты. Используйте вместо файла БД

Comment: полагаю, дело в синхронности скрипта. нужно сделать его асинхронным с применением asyncio

Comment: Вы запускаете 40-50 копий бота с одним и тем же ключом? Или все же запущена одна программа бот и к боту присоединилось 40-50 пользователей? Разница принципиальная

Comment: @RomanKonoval  что значит "копий"?

Comment: Вы пишете "Пробовал запускать программу с двух компьютеров, всё нормально", т.е. вы на двух копьютерах запустили этот бот, т.е. питон программу с кодом бота?

Comment: Нет. два телеграма

Comment: с двух телеграмов зашёл

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что библиотека telebot не асинхронная и в целом не предназначена для работы с большим количеством юзеров в связке с базами данных (или как в твоем случае с `naames.txt`)

Тут я могу только предложить переписать бота на **aiogram**. Сам он похож на telebot, однако лучше работает с фильтрами и в целом асинхронен

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: telebot поддерживает оба режима и синхронный и асинхронный. Асинхронный под капотом использует asyncio и очень даже нормально работает с большим количеством пользователей. А тут проблема в другом, а именно в многопоточном, как и асинхронном, коде нужно разделяемые ресурсы защищать. Простой переход на асинхронность ничего не даст.

Comment: Так что ответ неправильный. Нужно исправлять корень проблемы - а именно неправильную работу с многопоточностью/асинхронностью.